# WPF grid percentage width not working for elements with big width

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="123"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                       Background="LightGray"
                       Text="long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long "/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="123"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Background="LightYellow" Text="short"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

simple example, two grids with the same 30%/70% width of the window and window is set to SizeToContent width and height.

The expected behavior should be that the window is auto resized to a point where the long string is occupying 70% of the width.

But instead this is what happens
[image]

When I click on the border of the window (fire the resize event)
[image]

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

P.S. the second row is just to show the actual 30%/70% ratio, my main goal is to have the window auto resize to fit the long string with the correct ratio

Edit: even if I do text wrapping/text trimming I am not able to get the correct ratio

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
           Background="LightGray"
           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
           Text="long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long "/>
```

The window looks same as before

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping(v=vs.110).aspx perhaps?

Comment: @Will no luck. and still it doesn't explain the auto size problem

Comment: SizeToContent is automatically set to Manual if a user resizes the window by using the resize grip or dragging the border or if the size of the content changes in a way that causes the window to resize itself, SizeChanged is raised. This bevahviour is documented on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can repro.  The StackPanel at the root is probably going to hide the true window content's length from the root Window.  No idea how you'd accomplish this using standard controls, sorry.

Comment: @mm8 yea I know, just showing that under manual resize mode I can get the expected ratio which I cant under auto size mode.

Comment: Your "expected behavior" is apparently not the actual behaviour. Why don't you just set the SizeToContent to Manual and specify an initial width of the window?

Comment: @mm8 because I don't know how long the text would be and I would like the window to auto resize itself while keeping the column ratio

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719453/why-does-star-sizing-in-a-nested-grid-not-work. Note that setting `SizeToContent` relies on the same basic behavior as the nested grid scenario in my question, in that the container is expected to resize itself according to the contained grid, but doesn't take into account the star-sizing. There are a number of useful work-arounds described in the answers to that question.

Comment: Well, star-sizing simply doesn't work if the grid size is calculated based on its content.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yea you are right. Kind of sux that this is not fixed a year later.